# How to attribute a Creative Commons website icon

Tags: internet, licensing, creative-commons

I want to use [this icon](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:OOjs_UI_icon_language-ltr.svg) on a public website. The Creative Commons license says I must give attribution. I've read [here](https://creativecommons.org/use-remix/attribution/) that to give proper attribution, you must put the work's name, author's name, source, and license next to the image. Since I'm using the image as a small icon, it won't work visually to put the attribution next to the image. What should I do to provide attribution without needing to put a bunch of text next to the icon?

Comment: Nothing on that page you linked says it has to go "next to the image"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a page on your website titled "Image attributions", to contain a list of the images and the attribution text. Place a link to your image attributions page in the footer of the website, along with the other links to things like your terms of service, privacy policy and cookie settings (as required).

Scroll down to see a footer with this kind of link.

This allows the image creator to be credited, which is good, however in this particular case, the probability of the creator exercising their right and suing someone for not following cc-by is pretty small (but of course that's not a reason not to give credit where it is due)

Answer (score 3):

You are not "citing" the image - a citation is a reference to a (scholarly) work from another work, you are attributing a work that you have directly copied.

The [licence](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en) tells you what you must do:

> Attribution — You must give [appropriate credit](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en#), provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. **You may do so in any reasonable manner**, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.

I highlighted the important point: they tell you what you must do, the how is up to you so long as it is reasonable.